# If else the best option?

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement

i'm working on a project and need to build a process flow. I have attached an image showing my process flow. On this moment I have absolutely no idea how to write this...Can you guys help me out?! At the moment I have this piece of code: But on the path Set=Yes|Complete=Yes it won't continue anymore

```
if (item.IsSet == "J")
{
    DialogResult isComplete = MessageBox.Show("Zijn alle bijlagen meegeleverd?", "Bijlagen compleet?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
    if (isComplete == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        // Break out of this loop and continue
    }
    if (isComplete == DialogResult.No)
    {
        // STATUS NIET INGELEVERD
        MessageBox.Show("STATUS NIET INGELEVERD"); 
    }
}
if (item.IsSet == "N")
{
    if (item.DeliveryMethod == "N")
    {
        DialogResult geaccepteerd = MessageBox.Show("Let op: Dit boek is nieuw geleverd. Accepteer je de kwaliteit van dit boek?", "Kwaliteit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        if (geaccepteerd == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            // STATUS GEACCEPTEERD
            MessageBox.Show("STATUS GEACCEPTEERD");
        }
        if (geaccepteerd == DialogResult.No)
        {
            // STATUS NIET GEACCEPTEERD
            MessageBox.Show("STATUS NIET GEACCEPTEERD");
        }
    }
    if (item.DeliveryMethod == "G")
    {
        // STATUS GEACCEPTEERD
        MessageBox.Show("STATUS GEACCEPTEERD");
    }
}
```

[image: My attachment with process flow]

Comment: "I have absolutely no idea how to write this" - Well, do you have at least a knowledge of what your program is supposed to do?

Comment: I don't even see a loop here...

Comment: Process flows are usually a terrible way to describe programs.

Comment: Encapsulation. Write a method/function for each question/check.

Comment: What language is this ? (Not C# but the one used in MessageBox)

Comment: If you want your stuff reviewed, take some time and make it apresentable - the very least ident your code properly and use the correct markup to display images

Comment: In the path you desribe, there's no instruction in the code provided... you may want to complete this...

Comment: @fotanus: Posting images seems to not be allowed with low rep.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth oh, didn't knew that. Thanks.

Comment: Wow what a reactions. I've been out of the world of programming for 3 years now and just started again. I'm not sure if anyone can see my image?

Comment: Please indicate what line of code you claim is not working.

Comment: @BenWieland - This can easily by solved by using the Visual Studio Debugger.

Comment: Where does it fail? Where is this loop you are talking about? It doesn't help that it's in another language. Why is item.DeliveryMethod and item.IsSet strings and not enums. What does the strings mean?

Comment: @DavidS. Maybe the commont on loop wasn't the best. I'm not sure if you can see my image that I've attached, but that's the flow I want to build. I have a book wich can be part of a set (with for example a cd in it). Then if both the book and cd are handed over to the employer, the program needs to continue and ask if the book was a new one. If so, ask for the status of the book. If good enough status will be 'Accepted' else 'Not accepted'. If the book wasn't a new one, then just set status to 'accepted'. If one of both, book and cd, isn't there just set the status to 'not handed in'.

Comment: so IsNew in the flowchart == deliveryMethod in the code?

Comment: @mcalex Yeah that's correct. If a book is new the corresponding DeliveryMethod is 'N' and if a book is already used than DeliveryMethod is 'G'

Comment: @DavidS. Thanks for the help! It worked and I marked your answer :) Yours was helpfull as well mcalex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok according to you comment and flowchart here is my suggestion to simplify it

```
if (item.IsSet)
{
    DialogResult isComplete = MessageBox.Show("Complete set?", "complete set?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
    if (isComplete == DialogResult.No)
        // Break out
}
if(item.IsNew)
{
    DialogResult goodQuality = MessageBox.Show("Is the quality good", "quality", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    if (goodQuality == DialogResult.No)
        //not accepted (break)
}
//if reached here, accepted
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do it.

```
if (item.IsSet == "J")
{
  if (MessageBox.Show("Zijn alle bijlagen meegeleverd?", "Bijlagen compleet?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
  {
    if (item.DeliveryMethod == "N")
    {
      if (MessageBox.Show("Let op: Dit boek is nieuw geleverd. Accepteer je de kwaliteit van dit boek?", "Kwaliteit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.Yes)
      {
         // STATUS GEACCEPTEERD
         MessageBox.Show("STATUS GEACCEPTEERD");
      }
      else
      {
         // STATUS NIET GEACCEPTEERD
         MessageBox.Show("STATUS NIET GEACCEPTEERD");
      }
    }    
  }
  else 
  {
    MessageBox.Show("STATUS NIET INGELEVERD"); 
  }
}
else
{
  if (item.DeliveryMethod == "N")
  {
    if (MessageBox.Show("Let op: Dit boek is nieuw geleverd. Accepteer je de kwaliteit van dit boek?", "Kwaliteit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
       // STATUS GEACCEPTEERD
       MessageBox.Show("STATUS GEACCEPTEERD");
    }
   else
    {
       // STATUS NIET GEACCEPTEERD
       MessageBox.Show("STATUS NIET GEACCEPTEERD");
    }
  }
}
```